# add remember me option in login page in django

Tags: python, django

I have a piece of code in which I defined (remember me) in, but it does not work properly. Where do you think my problem could be?

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       username = request.POST.get('username')
       password = request.POST.get('password')
       remember_me = request.POST.get('remeber_me')
       user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
       if user:
           auth.login(request, user)
           if not remember_me:
               request.session.set_expiry(0)
           else:
               request.session.set_expiry(1209600)
           return redirect('/')
    
       messages.info(request, 'Credentials invalid')
       return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: What is the value of `remember_me` when the checkbox is unchecked? It's not being cleaned by a form so it might not be a Falsy value.

Comment: @Jacinator <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember-me" class="agree-term"/>

Comment: You're missing an "m" in `request.POST.get('remeber_me')`